# return value as key on map reduce

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

Currently my views on couchdb always return something like this:

```
{
  "key":"somekey",
  "value":"somevalue"
}
```

I wonder if there's any way to return something like this:

```
{
  "somekey":"somevalue"
}
```

i need to access "somekey" directly without having to search the whole array for a key with "somekey" value on it.

Thanks

Comment: the `key` could be not only string, but as array (common case for composite keys) and as object (rare case due to no any warranty about keys order) - you may hit some problems for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a view, there is no direct way provided by CouchDB to return the collection of documents as anything but key/value as you've seen.

You'd need to map the data on the client side into a keyed index, or request the document by the key directly from the view:

```
/sample/_design/docs/_view/by_somekey?key="somekey"
```

If you're looking for a fast map option in JavaScript (avoiding calling a function for each iteration), you could just use this simple logic of course:

```
// docs are the documents returned from the view
var map={};
for(var i=0,len=docs.length;i<len;i++) {
  map[docs[i].key] = docs[i].value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with underscoreJS (http://underscorejs.org/#reduce).

```
var map = {
  "key":"somekey",
  "value":"somevalue"
};

var result = _.reduce(map, function(key, value){
    var result = {};
    result[key] = value
    return result;
});

alert(result.somekey);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BcYtw/1/

Comment: The original docs would be in an array, not a single object. Your code doesn't work for Bnif's case.

Comment: The first parameter is documented as list. As you can see in the _.map example, it could be an array or object.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the format or data for Couch queries, you can reformat it at your will with [list function](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ddocs/#list-functions). Something like this should work for you:

```
function(head, req){
  send('[');
  row = getRow();
  if (row){
    // here you make your own JS structure to be returned,
    // serialize it with toJSON() and send to client with send()

    // First row:
    var new_row = {};
    new_row[row.key] = row.value;
    send(toJSON(new_row));

    while(row = getRow()){
      // Next rows:
      send(',');
      var new_row = {};
      new_row[row.key] = row.value;
      send(toJSON(new_row));
    }
  }
  return ']';
}
```